# Nesting Routes in React Router v4 with Class Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nested, react-router

I know this question's already been answered, and I read the React Router docs regarding nested routes, but I still can't see how to make it work with my current React app. All the examples given for nesting routes with v4 are with functional components. But what if I have a class component and need to nest a route? For example, my main app component is at `/` and I want to add a route for a search page at `/search` and I need that route to be a nested route(child route?) because the search page needs to read from state and state is only accessed from the app component. So I tried the following (note the `<Route/>` at the bottom):

```
//App.js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {}
  }

  // various methods that interact with state defined here

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app-wrapper">
        <Title/>
        <SearchBar/>
        <ListPicker/>
        <ListPane/> 

        <Route path="/search" component={Search}/>
      </div>
    )
  }  
}
```

Here's `Search.js`:

```
class Search extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="search-wrapper">
        <SearchBar/>
        <ul className="search-results">

          /* Read state to populate list */

        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And I define the route to `App` in `index.js`:

```
const Root = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
};

render(<Root/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

With this setup nothing gets rendered when navigating to `/search`. Not sure what to do given the disparity between my setup and the examples I've found online.

Comment: Where is your BrowserRouter and history?

Comment: @ThomasK sorry about that. I define the router in index.js. See edited question.

Comment: Yea i literally had the same issue, I think you have to use render. I find the docs unhelpful. Check out this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UVQ0ATR0vpI

Answer (score 1):

Nothing gets rendered because you specify and exact match for path `/` and hence `/search` is not matched, just remove the `exact` prop from the route

You need to use it like

```
const Root = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Route path="/" component={App}/>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
};

render(<Root/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Yup, that's why I wasn't seeing anything. So now I have the search component rendering below `App`--which I guess makes sense given how that's where I'm defining the route--but how do I have just `Search` render at `/search`?

Comment: I guess by that you mean to only render Search and not App, if yes then you need to include it at parent Route i.e index.js and hve `<Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
         <Router path="/search" component={Search}/>
      </Switch>`

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to work. Plus I don't think `Search` would be a child/nested route of `App`, which is what I need it to be.

Comment: what do you want to happen

Comment: I only want `Search` to render when navigating to `/search` and only `App` to render when navigating to `/`, but I need `Search` to be a child route of `App` because `Search` needs to read data from state, which it can only do if it's a child route of `App`. With pre v4 nested routes this would work. But I'm not seeing a way to do this with v4.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use render for nested Routes in React-Router v4. Something like this.

```
<Router history={history}>
            <Route path="/" render={() => (
              <div>
                <Route path="/" component={HomeView} />
                <Route exact path="/search" component={Search}/>
              </div>
            )}/>
      </Router>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this only manages to render out `Search` twice below `App` when navigating to `/search`.